# sprintf interpolating a string into itself

Tags: c, printf

Have a look at this code:

```
char *c = "%c %s %c";
char *r = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
printf(c, 65, c, 66);
```

It works as I expect and prints `A %c %s %c B`. But when I try to use sprintf:

```
char *c = "%c %s %c";
char *r = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
sprintf(r, c, 65, c, 66);
printf(r);
```

It outputs `A    B`.
I know that if copying takes place between objects that overlap the results are undefined. I don't know if this applies to my case, since the source and destination don't overlap, only the format string and one of the arguments. My main question is how can I have the `printf` behavior without printing, but storing the result to memory. Btw I also tried with `sprintf` and it works unexpected as well.

Comment: `printf(r);` ---> `printf("%s ",r);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With

```
sprintf(r, c, 65, c, 66);
```

you indeed make `r` contain the string you expect. ***But*** then you do

```
printf(r);
```

which will interpret the `%` sequences in the string `r` and attempt to find matching arguments for it. Since there are no arguments passed you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to just print the string in `r` as it is, use e.g. [`puts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) instead:

```
puts(r);
```

---

This is the reason you should never pass a string input by a user as the format string to a `printf` family function. It's an incredibly bad security hole.